# Compound MySQL query issues

Tags: mysql

First, I would like to tell about the basic structure that I am following. Say I have a table named td_idea which has a structure like this:

```
|-------------------------------------------------------------------|
| idea_id  |  idea_name   |  idea_submitter_id   |   idea_status    |
|----------|--------------|----------------------|------------------|
```

Then I have a table called td_idea_contribution which is to show the contribution that user s have made on a particular idea:

```
|-------------------------------------------------|
| contribution_id  |  idea_id   |  submitter_id   |
|------------------|------------|-----------------|
```

And finally the td_idea_contribution_like table:

```
|-------------------------------------------------|
| like_id  |  contribution_id   |  submitter_id   |
|----------|--------------------|-----------------|
```

I want to display all the contribution based on a particular idea_id, 
each contribution listed will also show the number of votes on that particular contribution.

Here's what I am trying to achieve using the query:

```
$sql="SELECT td_idea.*,td_idea_contribution.*,COUNT(td_idea_contribution_like.*) AS tot_like 
                                      FROM td_idea,td_idea_contribution,td_idea_contribution_like
                                     WHERE td_idea.idea_id=td_idea_contribution.idea_id 
                                     AND td_idea_contribution.contribution_id=td_idea_contribution_like.contribution_id
                                     AND td_idea.idea_id='$id'
                                     AND td_idea_contribution.contribution_type='Design' ORDER BY tot_like DESC";
```

but the SQL string is showing me error. The error is as follows

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '*) AS td_idea_contribution_like.tot_like FROM' at line 1

Comment: Within `count` we can specify column name or *. In your query you are passing multiple columns as argument in the `count` function..

Answer (score 1):

`COUNT(td_idea_contribution_like.*)` is the problem here

`*` means You specified more than one column here.